# Wistia : How to redirect to new page when the video ends?

Tags: redirect, video, wistia

I am using wistia to host my videos 
Is there a way to redirect to a new URL at the end of the video ?

Answer (score -1):

It is pretty simple actually.
Go to Video actions then to customize and under the call for action you can put link to a site with call for action